# How do I control initial Size and positioning of labels and buttons in a splitter in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

It's me again, trying to understand Kivy concepts.

I have a widget with a base class of RelativeLayout containing a chessboard image displaying in a splitter. I want to display a label, and 2 buttons horizontally below the chessboard spaced a small distance away from the chessboard and still have everything resizable with splitter. I've tried numerous ways to no avail. What I currently have is this:

[image: Current GUI]

What I want is this: (How do I achieve it?)

[image: Desired GUI]

Here is the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.splitter import Splitter
from kivy.uix.image import Image

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class ChessBoardWidget(RelativeLayout):  # FloatLayout
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        repertoire_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        repertoire_boxlayout.add_widget(Label(text='Repertoire for:'))
        repertoire_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='White'))
        repertoire_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='Black'))

        chessboard_gui_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        chessboard_gui_boxlayout.add_widget(
            Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", pos=self.pos,
                  size_hint=(1, 1), keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True))
        chessboard_gui_boxlayout.add_widget(repertoire_boxlayout)
        self.add_widget(chessboard_gui_boxlayout)

class SplitterGui(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SplitterGui, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        # Splitter 1
        split1_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        split1 = Splitter(sizable_from='bottom', min_size=74, max_size=1100)

        chessboard_widget = ChessBoardWidget()  

        split1.add_widget(chessboard_widget) 
        split1_boxlayout.add_widget(split1)
        s3_button = Button(text='s3', size_hint=(1, 1))
        split1_boxlayout.add_widget(s3_button)
        self.add_widget(split1_boxlayout)

        # Splitter 2
        split2 = Splitter(sizable_from='left', min_size=74, max_size=1800)
        s2_button = Button(text='s2', size_hint=(.1, 1))
        split2.add_widget(s2_button)
        self.add_widget(split2)


class ChessBoxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SplitterGui()  # root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChessBoxApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `BoxLayout` (see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html)), you can use `size_hint` and `size` (or `height`, `width`) to adjust sizes. So, you can set the `height` of your `Buttons`, and let the `Image` use the remaining `height` of the `BoxLayout`:

```
class ChessBoardWidget(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        repertoire_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(1, None), height=30)  # set height of Buttons
        repertoire_boxlayout.add_widget(Label(text='Repertoire for:'))
        repertoire_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='White'))
        repertoire_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='Black'))

        chessboard_gui_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        chessboard_gui_boxlayout.add_widget(
            Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", pos=self.pos, keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True))  # default size_hint of (1,1) claims all of remaining height
        chessboard_gui_boxlayout.add_widget(repertoire_boxlayout)
        self.add_widget(chessboard_gui_boxlayout)
```

Comment: When I reduce the width of the BoxLayout with the buttons, it is on the left side of the splitter, can I center it like in the picture above?

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) `Position hints are partially working, depending on the orientation:

If the orientation is vertical: x, right and center_x will be used.

If the orientation is horizontal: y, top and center_y will be used.` So you can just add `pos_hint={'center_x':0.5}` when you create that `BoxLayout`